# useState cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to use the `useState` hook to set and change the images for a single product page. Using the same `useFetch` function to populate the previous page of all products, so it should be pulling the API data correctly. However I'm getting an error 'cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img').

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";

const Product = () => {
  const id = useParams().id;
  const [selectedImg, setSelectedImg] = useState("img");
  const [quantitiy, setQuantitiy] = useState(1);

  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(`/products/${id}?populate=*`);
```

```js
<div className="images">
  <img
    src={
      process.env.REACT_APP_UPLOAD_URL +
      data?.attributes?.img?.data?.attributes?.url
    }
    alt=""
    onClick={(e) => setSelectedImg("img")}
  />
  <img
    src={
      process.env.REACT_APP_UPLOAD_URL +
      data?.attributes?.img2?.data?.attributes?.url
    }
    alt=""
    onClick={(e) => setSelectedImg("img2")}
  />
</div>
<div className="mainImg">
  <img
    src={
      process.env.REACT_APP_UPLOAD_URL +
      data?.attributes[selectedImg]?.data?.attributes?.url
    }
    alt=""
  />
</div>
```

I've been reading through the React docs and it seems like this should work. The image attribute of each item in the data is called 'img'.

Comment: There are big parts of the code missing, but I would start debugging this at data?.attributes[selectedImg]?.data?.attributes?.url. Console log it just before return/render and make sure that data?.attributes exist at all times. I am assuming this is the line that breaks and it breaks cause there is no data.attributes and therefore it can't find data.attributes['img']

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data?.attributes?.[selectedImg]?.data?.attributes?.url`

Comment: Hi. IMHO this might be the answer, but the stackowerflow encourages complete answers, not one-liners. Please consider explaining WHY you think this is a solution. I will not set the Recommend deletion flag because I think this can be valid (can't be sure - lack of code on part of the question asker)

Answer (score 0):

In your useFetch.js make it const [data,setData]= useState(null) instead of useState([]). Hope it helps